# Generics C# organization of methods that depends on type

Tags: c#, generics, nested-generics

I'm Tryng to made a base class with a base method that order a List with a function that depends on Type.

My Compiler show this Error

Error   13  Impossibile to convert 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<MLOLPlus.Business.Dealer,string>>' in 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<T,string>>'.   D:\Documenti\Lavori\timage\MLOLPlus\src\MLOLPlus.Business\DataAcess\DataTablesClasses\DataTableMultiSort.cs 197 20  MLOLPlus.Business

IdentityEntity is a base abstract class base of all Custom Class Data type

Example:

1. User inherits IdentityEntity
2. Editor too

Base Class MultiSort:

```
public class DataTableMultiSort
{

    public DataTableParameterModel DataTable { get; set; }

    public IQueryable<T> MultiSort<T>(IQueryable<T> basequery) where T : IdentityEntity{
        return CreateSortedQuery<T>(basequery, DataTable);
    }

    private IOrderedQueryable<T> CreateSortedQuery<T>(IQueryable<T> baseQuery, DataTableParameterModel parameterModel) where T : IdentityEntity
    {
        var orderedQuery = (IOrderedQueryable<T>)baseQuery;

        for (int i = 0; i < parameterModel.iSortingCols; ++i)
        {
            var ascending = string.Equals("asc", parameterModel.sSortDir[i], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            int sortCol = parameterModel.iSortCol[i];

            Expression<Func<T, string>> orderByExpression = GetOrderingFunc<T>(sortCol);
            if (orderByExpression != null)
            {
                ...do things
            }
            else
            {
                if (ascending)
                {
                    orderedQuery = (i == 0)
                        ? orderedQuery.OrderBy(c => c.Id)
                        : orderedQuery.ThenBy(c => c.Id);
                }
                else
                {
                    ...
                }
            }

        }
        return orderedQuery;
    }

    protected virtual Expression<Func<T, string>> GetOrderingFunc<T>(int ColumnIndex) where T : IdentityEntity
    {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Custom User Multisort

```
  public class UserMultiSort : DataTableMultiSort
    {
        protected override Expression<Func<T, string>> GetOrderingFunc<T>(int ColumnIndex)
        {
            Expression<Func<User, string>> InitialorderingFunction;
            switch (ColumnIndex)
            {
                case 1:
                    InitialorderingFunction = c => c.FirstName;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    InitialorderingFunction = c => c.LastName;
                    break;
                default:
                    InitialorderingFunction = null;
                    break;
            }

            return InitialorderingFunction;
        }

    }
```

Custom Editor Multisort

```
public class EditorMultiSort : DataTableMultiSort
{
    protected override Expression<Func<T, string>> GetOrderingFunc<T>(int ColumnIndex)
    {
        Expression<Func<Editor, string>> InitialorderingFunction;
        switch (ColumnIndex)
        {
            case 1:
                InitialorderingFunction = c => c.BusinessName;
                break;
            case 2:
                InitialorderingFunction = c => c.Address;
                break;
            default:
                InitialorderingFunction = null;
                break;
        }

        return InitialorderingFunction;
    }

}
```

Comment: yes, my mistake, but isn't very important compiler error after reading the code, i assume that's a organization lack in my classes

Comment: I do no understand italian, but the compiler complains about a class you did not include: RetailerMultiSort

Comment: Please reduce your code into the [shortest possible complete compilable example](http://sscce.org/) to focus your question.

Comment: ok, i've posted not the right error!Going to edit!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're getting the compiler error is that you've pushed the generic constrains to the individual methods rather than putting the restraint on the *class*.  The way you have it, there's no way to override the intrinsically generic method  `GetOrderingFunc<T>` with a method that returns a `Expression<Func<User, string>>`.

What you've posted works if you make `DataTableMultiSort` generic and take the generic paramteres off of the methods:

```
public class DataTableMultiSort<T> where T : IdentityEntity
{
...
    protected virtual Expression<Func<T, string>> GetOrderingFunc(int ColumnIndex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public class UserMultiSort : DataTableMultiSort<User>
{
    protected override Expression<Func<User, string>> GetOrderingFunc(int ColumnIndex)
    {
        Expression<Func<User, string>> InitialorderingFunction;
        ...
     }
}
```

Comment: The question is whether he can instantiate the `DataTableMultiSort`  based on `T`.

Comment: @galenus Is it?  I don't see that anywhere in the question - I just addressed the compiler error.

Comment: @D Stanley of course you did, and for that I upvote your answer. But I'm not sure it is a solution for his problem.

Comment: @galenus The compiler error is the only problem that's been identified. If the OP wants to override the generic method with a non-generic method the answer is "you can't".  Making the _classes_ generic lets you return the desired type.

Comment: @andrea take the generic constraints off of the methods: `IOrderedQueryable<T> CreateSortedQuery(IQueryable<T> baseQuery, DataTableParameterModel parameterModel)`

Comment: @andrea You should, something wrong with your fix.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64327/discussion-between-galenus-and-d-stanley).